# Getting "Can't Access Variable:AccessToken" on Android emulator

Tags: facebook-login, react-native

I'm using react-native to develop my Android Mobile App with facebook authentication. After successfully logging into my facebook user account on my Android emulator I get an error on the screen :

> "Can't access variable: AccessToken"

Wondering if I'm missing any thing in my setup.

Need help!

Here is the code I used in `index.android.js` :

```
<LoginButton

              onLoginFinished={

              (error, result) => {

              if (error) {

                console.log("login has error: " + result.error);

              } else if (result.isCancelled) {

                console.log("login is cancelled.");

              } else {

                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(

                  (data) => {

                    console.log(data);

                  }

                )

              }

            }

          }

          onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
```

Error screen on my android emulator here:

[image: Error screen on my android emulator here]

Thanks
LAxmikant

Comment: You receive the `AccessToken` on logging in which you'll need for the requests. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: Could you please elaborate if its an expected behaviour I need to fix something on my end.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to be provoked by the provided code, do you do other requests?

Comment: Dont know if you have solved this, but you have forgot to import the AcessToken from the facebook SDK in your Component.